# Angular - URL with ID ok or should I be using title - Slug advantage?

Tags: angularjs, url, slug

At the moment in my Angular app, I'm using URLs with the ID e.g.

```
mysite.com/story/34jkh4432jkdasddasdsadasdas3
```

For what reasons would it be beneficial if any to instead do something like:

```
mysite.com/story/34jkh4432jkdasddasdsadasdas3/the-story-title
```

Is it strongly recommended? (e.g. for helping SEO) (An obvious advantage i see is if the URL is shared, easier for people to know roughly what they are about to see).

Else wouldn't the URL just become really long?

Also to implement it - I presume I can technically ignore the 'slug title' as its just that long ID i use? It would just be there for SEO/user readability.
Is that the correct way to think of it?
I notice even on this page, if I remove anything after the post ID it still takes me to the correct page.

Thanks.

Comment: look up to the address bar right now :-) Yes, it does make sense imo

Comment: Yep - that's actually what reminded me to look into it :-) But technically can it be there in the URL but be ignored if I'm using the ID as the main thing to retrieve data.